# how to upload , edit and download image in react js im trying but old image only downloaded im new so help me out

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to upload an image in react to edit means adding some css and text and then i want to download that image

im expecting to download my edited image so help me out im new to react js
its uploading page

```
 const [imgData, setImgData] = useState(null);
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [fname, setFname] = useState('');
    const [date, setDate] = useState('');
    const [time, setTime] = useState('');
    const [day, setDay] = useState('');
    const [month, setMonth] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
    const nav = useNavigate();
    const onChangePicture = (e) => {
      if (e.target.files[0]) {
        console.log("picture: ", e.target.files);
        setPicture(e.target.files[0]);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
          setImgData(reader.result);
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
      }
    };
    const user={
        image:imgData,
        name:name,
        fname:fname,
        day:day,
        time:time,
        month:month,   
        date:date,
        address:address
    }
    const onClick = ( ) => {
        props.sendData(user);
        nav('/output')
      };
    return (
        <>
        <h3>image</h3>
            <input id="profilePic" type="file" onChange={onChangePicture} />
            <h3>groom</h3>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} />
            <h3>bride</h3>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setFname(e.target.value)} />
            <h3>day</h3>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setDay(e.target.value)} />
            <h3>time</h3>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setTime(e.target.value)} />
            <h3>date</h3>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setDate(e.target.value)} />
            <h3>month</h3>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setMonth(e.target.value)} />
            <h3>address</h3>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setAddress(e.target.value)} />
            
            <button onClick={onClick}>Click Here</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default Image;
```

its output page
import styled from "styled-components";

```
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Sec>
        <img src={data.image} alt="" />
      </Sec>
      <Sec2>
        <Head>
          <Welcome>Together with </Welcome>
          <Welcome2>their family </Welcome2>
        </Head>
        <Name>{data.name}</Name>
        <To>&amp; </To>
        <Sname>{data.fname}</Sname>
      </Sec2>
      <Sec3>
        <Below>Request the pleasure of your company at</Below>
        <Below2> the ceremony of their wedding</Below2>
      </Sec3>
      <Sec4>
        <Below4>{data.day} </Below4>
        <Date>{data.date} </Date>
        <Below5>At {data.time} </Below5>
        <Month>{data.month}</Month>
      </Sec4>
      <Sec5>
        <Place>{data.address}</Place>
        <Place2>Reception to follow</Place2>
      </Sec5>
    </Container>
  );
};
type here
```

detail is ablove im writing becauser it asking me more detail and and all 220 words etc
tq
help me out